# How to print in dask future without breaking progress bar?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am using dask distributed to run many tasks, some of which print some status output. These prints interrupt the progress bar and look ugly.

Minimal example:

```py
from time import sleep
from dask.distributed import Client, progress


def slow_func(n):
    sleep(n)
    if n % 2:
        print('this print interrupts the progress bar')


def run():
    client = Client()

    futures = client.map(slow_func, range(5))

    progress(*futures)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

output:

```
[#######                                 ] | 19% Completed |  0.9sthis print interrupts the progress bar
[########################                ] | 60% Completed |  2.9sthis print interrupts the progress bar
```

desired:

```
this print did not interrupt the progress bar
this print did not interrupt the progress bar
[########################                ] | 60% Completed |  2.9s
```

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> Any way to do this?

Not to my knowledge, no.

Comment: Thanks. My workaround was to add "\r" to the beginning of each print().